# How to add rhs value to class in C++ (operator overloading)

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I have a matrix class and I want to overload the `*` operator in c++ to multiply a scalar to the matrix.. I am able to achieve..

```
matrix1 * matrix2
matrix1 * 5
```

but I also want `5 * matrix1` to work.

How to achieve this.. Idk what to search for this, nothing is coming related :|

Comment: You'd likely benefit from reading [this answer to "What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/364696). Short version: The class implements `*=` as a member function, then you implement both directions in terms of it using non-member functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this, calling your existing `matrix * scalar` function with the arguments reversed:

```
inline matrix operator*(int scalar, const matrix& mat) {
    return mat * scalar;
}
```

The above is a free function, to be declared in whatever namespace `matrix` is in, not inside the class.